# Can I say "on the first sign" instead of "at"?

Tags: grammar, prepositions

For me differentiating prepositions *at*, *in*, and *on* are very difficult. Now I found the following sentence over [Duolingo French course](https://forum.duolingo.com/comment/7294254):

> At the first road sign, turn left.

This is the translation from the following French sentence, if you want to know:

> Au premier panneau, tournez à gauche.

I typed in *on* and got notified that *at* is the correct answer. But I'm not sure if the course creator has not added *on* to the list of acceptable answers (very common on Duolingo and in that case users report it), or it is simply wrong in grammar.

So it the use of *on* correct or not in this sentence, and why?

Comment: BTW is *on* the correct preposition for *Duolingo* ...?

Comment: If you mean instead of *over* in your second sentence, yes *on* would be correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*At* is the better word to use here. *At* carries a lot meanings related to being near its object. In this context, *at* means physically nearby, but also carries the connotation of (in the words of the OED) "some practical connection with a place". So not only does this use convey that the left turn is to occur physically close to the stop sign, it implies that the stop sign has a connection to the action of turning.

As the listener is assumed to know, the stop sign would be placed at an intersection, and the understanding is that the person following the directions would realize that they are supposed to turn left onto the road crossing the intersection. In contrast, we wouldn't say *near the stop sign*, even though it is technically true, because it doesn't have the implication that the stop sign is an inherent part of using the road.

As far as *on* goes, I think a case could be made for it by using the sense in which *on* refers to a point in time, or a point in a series of events. It would mean something like "on encountering the stop sign". The problem with this is that *on* has the very commonly used meaning of being physically in contact with, or on top of its object. (Obviously, being physically on a stop sign is far enough away from a likely instruction that it wouldn't cause anyone real confusion.)

For all I know, "on the stop sign" might be idiomatic in some regions, but I think "at the stop sign" is what is generally used, as well as being more correct. By the way, *at* is generally used in the same way for other indicators in directions: "at the curve in the road", "turn at the mailbox", "at the fork in the road", "at the third house on the left", etc.